# Flutter Notifications / Parsing error: Unexpected token admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to message a user when a new item got uploaded from a other user he subscribed to.

**My Way to approach this:**

First I check if a new item gets uploaded.
When this is true I want get the uid from the user who uploaded the item.
Then I go to the file of the User (User/{uid from the user who uploaded the item}), where the accounts that subscribed to him are in a list of Strings with their uids.
For each uid in this List, I want to get the the devicetoken from the user with this specific uid (User/{uid from List}/devicetoken) and add each devicetoken to a list of strings.
With this devicetoken I finally want to send a message to each device in this list.
But Im not that experienced with js and backend developing.

My Code is following the descriped way but I get some warings when I try to deploy it to the firebase functions.

**warnings when deploying to firebase:**

> 24:17  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting

> 24:17  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting

> 30:26  warning  Don't make functions within a loop  no-loop-func

> 46:20  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting

> 46:20  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting

Can someone of you help me with my Problem :)?

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initalizeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var msgData;

//listen for new uploades
exports.recipeTrigger = functions.firestore.document('item/{itemId}').onCreate(async(snapshot) => {
msgData = snapshot.data();

//get dat from the user that uploaded the item
await admin.firestore().collection('User/' + msgData.uid).get().then((snapshots) => {
    var users = [];
    var tokens = [];
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No Users');
        return null;
    } else {
        //get every user uid
        users = snapshots.data().subscribers;
        for (user of users) {
            //user should be the uid
            admin.firestore().collection('User/' + user).get().then((snap) => {
                for (var token of snap.docs) {
                    //add devicetoken to a list Avoid nesting promises
                    tokens.add(token.data().token);
                }
                return tokens;
            }).catch(error => { print(error) })
            return users;
        }
        //specify message content
        var payload = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": "From" + snapshots.data().displayName,
                    "body": "I uploaded a new Recipe",
                    "sound": "default",
                },
                "data": {
                    "senderName": snapshots.data().displayName,
                    "message": snapshots.data().displayName + "uploaded a new Recipe",
                }
            }
            //send message to devicetokens
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
            console.log('Notifications send');
            return response;
        }).catch((er) => {
            console.log(er);
        });
    }
}).catch(error => { print(error) });
})
```

Comment: You have a bunch of different javascript lint errors here.  You should track them down individually.  If you don't know what each one means, you should do a web search using the error message to learn more.

Comment: I fixed all the errors but I now get a new error:

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you to look at line 23 with the `firestore` token:

```
await firestore().document('User/' + user).get().then((snap) => {
```

You probably meant to say `admin.firestore().doc(...)`.

Comment: I simply removed the await and added some other changes but i still get a bunch of warnings, do you know why @DougStevenson?

Comment: If you have a new problem, that should be posted as a new question along with the details of what isn't working the way you expect.